# Django Model Form Image Field Does Not Validate

Tags: django, django-forms, django-file-upload

I am writing a simple view using Django Model Form, however image field fails to validate with 'This field is required' error message.

I wonder where the problem is...

Model:

```
class Deal(AbstractModel):
    IMAGE_MAX_LENGTH = 200

    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, related_name='deals', related_query_name='deal', verbose_name=_("Place"))
    image = models.ImageField(default='deals/default.png', max_length=IMAGE_MAX_LENGTH, upload_to='deals', verbose_name=_("Image"))
    ...
```

View:

```
@login_required
def deals_create(request):
    # Get place id
    place_id = request.GET.get('place')
    # Get place
    place = Place.objects.get(id=place_id)
    # Process form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DealsCreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        # Validate post data
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save deal data
            deal = form.save(commit=False)
            deal.place = place
            deal.save()
            # Redirect to reload page and clear post data
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('deal_manager:deals_pending'))
    else:
        form = DealsCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'deal_manager/deals_create.html', {
        'form': form,
        'place': place,
    })
```

Form:

```
class DealsCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Deal
        fields = [
            'image', 'product_name', 'product_description',
            'regular_price', 'sale_price', 'limit', 'terms',
        ]
```

Template:

```
{% extends "deal_manager/deal_manager.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block page_content_body %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <form action="{% url 'deal_manager:deals_create' %}?place={{ place.id }}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Create' %}" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gap gap-small"></div>
{% endblock page_content_body %}
```

Note: Form validates when I remove the image field from form meta fields.

Note: File uploads works fine with Django Admin for this model.

Comment: Can you include your template code?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the template code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in order to bind imagefield and filefield data to the form. Without that, those fields won't validate.

```
{% block page_content_body %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'deal_manager:deals_create' %}?place={{ place.id }}" method="post">
                    ...
```

Here's the relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: I knew it was a simple one, but we do need an extra eye when things get messy. Thank you!